# sql ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm running the following SQL syntax:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT<DISTINCT<EMP_NUM>> "Number of Employees"
        FROM HOURS;`
```

But it's not working. I'm getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT<EMP_NUM>> "Number of Employees" FROM HOURS' at line 1

Could you please guide me on where I am doing a mistake? Sorry, I'm new to MySQL and databases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `()` instead of `<>` like this:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EMP_NUM) "Number of Employees" from HOURS;
```